# Webpack / Vuejs - Changing path of assets?

Tags: webpack, path, assets, vue-cli

*(Coming from Gulp, I am new to Vue and Webpack)*

I have made a small Vue app using the vue-cli. 
My paths in the webpack config file are currently set up like this:

```
assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
assetsSubDirectory: 'assets',
assetsPublicPath: '../'
```

This results, as expected, in the following:

**index.html**: `../assets/css/app.css`

**app.css**: `../assets/img/myimage.png`

---

The problem is that my assets aren't served from this location on the production server. This is also out of my control. Right now, I need to manually (after build, using replaceAll) change the paths to this:

**index.html**: `assets/css/app.css`

**app.css**: `../img/myimage.png`

Is there a way to automate this in Webpack? I have tried multiple different `assetsPublicPath`'s. But seeing that I need 2 different paths for index.html and app.css, this has no effect..

Any idea's? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
assetsPublicPath: './'
```

instead of

```
assetsPublicPath: '../'
```

if you are on windows machine.